# When i change select tag why not show data in input id="message"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i change select tag why not show data in input `id="message"` ?

and if i want to show default = 90 in input `id="message"` , how can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Wf3g2/283/

```
<select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange()">
  <option value="5">Get Married</option>
  <option value="100">Have a Baby</option>
  <option value="90">Adopt a Child</option>
  <option value="15">Retire</option>
  <option value="15">Military Leave</option>
  <option value="15">Medical Leave</option>
</select>

<input id="message">

<script>
function leaveChange() {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = document.getElementById("leave").value;   
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you actually wanted a `jQuery` answer (as tagged) is is even simpler (I wanted to test the new "code snippet" option too, hence this edit):

```js
$('#leave').change(function(){
    $('#message').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="leave">
  <option value="5">Get Married</option>
  <option value="100">Have a Baby</option>
  <option value="90">Adopt a Child</option>
  <option value="15">Retire</option>
  <option value="15">Military Leave</option>
  <option value="15">Medical Leave</option>
</select>

<input id="message">
```

With jQuery you do not need (or desire) to use `onclick` handlers in elements so I have removed that. As you can see it is much cleaner to register *and* handle the event with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like:

```
var e = document.getElementById("leave");
document.getElementById("message").value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.innerHTML` to `.value`.

To have a default value set it in the HTML:

```
<input id="message" value="90"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wf3g2/284/

Answer (score 0):

Because `<input>`s don't have the `innerHTML` property, they use `value`:

```
document.getElementById("message").value = document.getElementById("leave").value;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wf3g2/285/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions would be:

**HTML**:

```
<body onload="leaveChange()">
    <select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange()">
      <option value="5">Get Married</option>
      <option value="100">Have a Baby</option>
      <option value="90" selected="selected">Adopt a Child</option>
      <option value="15">Retire</option>
      <option value="15">Military Leave</option>
      <option value="15">Medical Leave</option>
    </select>

    <input id="message"/>
</body>
```

**javascript**:

```
function leaveChange() {
    document.getElementById("message").value = document.getElementById("leave").value;   
}
```

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/Wf3g2/287/) to see a working example.
Hope it's useful!